# Finding commits that were reverted by an author

Tags: git, audit, git-revert, author

The subject mostly covers it, but to avoid any ambiguity - I'm interested in auditing how often a particular developer has had commits reverted (who does the revert doesn't matter).  I can't seem to find anything searching (my google-fu is failing me here).

For example, consider this commit history:

```
* 76b203f "gddc" 37 seconds ago (HEAD -> master)
| Revert "file 1 added"
* 6da3eea "gddc" 52 seconds ago
| file2 added
* c940460 "gddc" 61 seconds ago
  file 1 added
```

At a glance its' easy to see that I've reverted commit 1 here, but I'd like a programmatic way to audit that against any repository for any author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to note that `git` doesn't record any sort of metadata that says "this commit reverts that commit".  While `git` will *suggest* a default commit message that says, "This reverts commit ...", nothing prevents someone from changing that message.  As long as you're confident that people are maintaining the default message, you can find revert commits doing something like...

```
git log --grep reverts
```

That will give you output like:

```
commit 563a99c7bd36998afb7a1957eaf29b0966402a77 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Example User <user@example.com>
Date:   Mon Jan 15 14:35:36 2018 -0500

    Revert "first"

    This reverts commit 131e6f65c9a78c5476921b6c2f8632661a2d71b6.
```

You'll want to produce a list of reverted commit ids.  You could pipe that output into `awk`, like this:

```
git log --grep reverts | awk '/This reverts commit/ {print $4}' | cut -f1 -d.
```

Which gets you a list of commit ids:

```
131e6f65c9a78c5476921b6c2f8632661a2d71b6
```

You can feed that list into `xargs` to look up information about the original commits, e.g:

```
git log --grep reverts | 
  awk '/This reverts commit/ {print $4}' | cut -f1 -d. |
  xargs -iCID git show --quiet --format='%ae' CID
```

The above uses `%ae` to extract the author email from each reverted commit, e.g.:

```
new_dev@example.com
```

You could modify the argument to `--format` to output other information about the original commit.

Does this point you in the right direction?

Comment: Yeah, that's a great place to start!  Thank you!  It surprises me that there's not metadata saved when reverting a commit - that seems like something that would be valuable.  In any event, I think this gives me a good jumping-off point.  Much appreciated!